Are integer runs the hardest sets of a certain size to cover with prime-gap arithmetic progressions?
Let $N$ be a positive integer. What is the smallest size of a set $S$ of integers satisfying this property: for each integer $k$, the set $$\{s + k \mid s \in S\}$$ contains a number coprime to $N$?
Randomly generating sets suggests that the answer is given by $g(N) = $ https://oeis.org/A048669$(N)$. (The sequences probably agree for all $N < 1000$.) This implies that one example of a minimal set $S$ is a run of $g(N)$ consecutive integers, which definitely satisfies the property, but is not obviously minimal.
If it is minimal, the rough idea in the title question is correct. To elaborate, suppose $S$ is a set of $c$ integers. Assume there is a run of $c$ consecutive integers, none of which are coprime to $N$. (As such, $c \le g(N)-1$.) Then is there an integer $k$ so that none of the elements of $\{s + k \mid s \in S\}$ are coprime to $N$? Equivalently, if $c$ consecutive integers can be covered by $\omega(N)$ arithmetic progressions, one with common difference $p$ for each prime factor $p$ of $N$, then can any set of $c$ integers be covered by these arithmetic progressions?
We can assume $N$ is squarefree and $S \subseteq [1,N]$.
The motivation for this question is that I am looking at particular sets of $p$ numbers whose translates all apparently contain a number coprime to $p^2-1$ for some prime $p$, and I would like insight into these kinds of non-coverable sets, even though $p$ is generally much larger than $g(p^2-1)$ so a positive or negative result here is not exactly applicable.
